# ESLint / VSCode, the whole object is underlined

Tags: eslint, visual-studio-code

Since the last VSCode or Eslint extension update, the whole object is underlined when an error or a warning is detected. An idea why ?

[image]

Comment: Please share a complete code sample. It seems like you are using an unnamed function, but the screenshot does not show where the error starts

Answer (score 0):

I’m guessing you’re exporting this function from Webpack configuration module. I can think of two options that come to play.

First, define named function:

```
module.exports = function withBaseConfiguration() {
    return { /* configuration goes here */ }
}
```

Second, disable the ESLint rule for *this* file by placing following at the top:

```
/* eslint-disable func-names */
```